# Holoviews heatmap animation labelling slider

Tags: python-3.x, animation, bokeh, heatmap, holoviews

I have created an animated heatmap using holoviews with the 'bokeh' renderer.  The code is below and runs in a Jupyter Notebook.  Basically I compose a dictionary of heatmaps then I use 'hv.DynamicMap' and 'hv.streams' to create the animation ie. stream keys of dict and render the associated heatmap.

The code runs successfully as an animation but produces an output where a single frame looks like this:
[image]

I have two questions:

- I want the slider to show the 'key' of the dictionary not just the
  index of the list of keys as it does now. So in the image above 'a0' not '0'.  How can I do that?
- there are warnings being thrown about 'fixed_width'.  I have set the
  height and width of all the objects so why is there a warning?

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv

from bokeh.io import show, curdoc, output_notebook
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.models import Slider, Button

renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh').instance(mode='server')
output_notebook()

# generate a dict of heatmaps
heatmap_dict = {}

for i in range(10):
    heatmap = hv.HeatMap((np.random.randint(0, 10, 100), np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 100),
                          np.random.randn(100), np.random.randn(100)), vdims=['z', 'z2']).sort().aggregate(function=np.mean)
    heatmap.opts(height=400, width=400)
    heatmap_dict['a' + str(i)] = heatmap

heatmap_keys = list(heatmap_dict.keys())

# Create the holoviews app again
def mapping(phase):
    key = heatmap_keys[phase]
    return heatmap_dict[key]

stream = hv.streams.Stream.define('Phase', phase=0)()


dmap = hv.DynamicMap(mapping, streams=[stream])

# Define valid function for FunctionHandler
# when deploying as script, simply attach to curdoc
def modify_doc(doc):
    # Create HoloViews plot and attach the document
    hvplot = renderer.get_plot(dmap, doc)

    # Create a slider and play buttons
    def animate_update():
        year = slider.value + 1
        if year > end:
            year = start
        slider.value = year

    def slider_update(attrname, old, new):
        # Notify the HoloViews stream of the slider update 
        stream.event(phase=new)
        
    start, end = 0, len(heatmap_keys) - 1
    slider = Slider(start=start, end=end, value=start, step=1, title="Phase", height=30, width=180)
    slider.on_change('value', slider_update)
    
    callback_id = None

    def animate():
        global callback_id
        if button.label == '► Play':
            button.label = '❚❚ Pause'
            callback_id = doc.add_periodic_callback(animate_update, 50)
        else:
            button.label = '► Play'
            doc.remove_periodic_callback(callback_id)
    button = Button(label='► Play', width=60, height=30)
    button.on_click(animate)
    
    # Combine the holoviews plot and widgets in a layout
    plot = layout([
    [hvplot.state],
    [slider, button]], sizing_mode='fixed')
    
    doc.add_root(plot)
    return doc

# To display in the notebook
show(modify_doc, notebook_url='localhost:8888')
```